# Getting Admin Instance after multi auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

```
 'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

I have added this in providers array,

and

```
'admin' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'admins',
            ],
```

in guards array in config\auth.php

After I successfully logged in as an admin, how do I get admin instance in view, just as a user?

```
{{auth()->user()->username}}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write this to get the instance of admin

```
{{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->username }}
```

This will solve your problem.